# WCF service host in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a mobile application that interacts with a WCF service.

Do I have to host the wcf in IIS in order for the mobile to connect to it via internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS is one hosting option, others include WAS (Windows Activation Service), and self-hosting it in an application you write. These options are all well described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).

As long as the server is accessible on the internet, any hosting option will work. They all have various pros and cons, such as reliability, accounting, and simplicity.

Comment: can a windows service be an option for internet ? or it's only intranet?

Comment: Yes you can host WCF service exposed to Internet on Windows service but generally IIS is better choice because it has a lot of out of the box functionality.